# Magento configuration of custom module - how to use controller/layout etc to show pop up window?

Tags: magento

I have tried asking this question in bits, but with limited success.

I am writing a custom module. The custom module has a configuration aspect. In that configuration, I want to pop up a window that contains fields where the user enters further information (rather than have that those fields directly on the configuration screen).

So I have a button on the configuration screen that, if pressed, opens this new window (using javascript's window.open). Just to test the mechanism, I put the file to be opened in the root of my Magento installation and that was fine. But clearly I will need to put that file somewhere else. So instead of opening abc.html, I had the javascript open /index.php/myfrontname/mycontroller/myaction (I'd rather not have index.php in my URLs, but that's another thing altogether).

Firstly, is changing the url from a plain html file to a frontname/controller/action structure the correct thing to do?

Assuming it is, I do not get the content I was expecting on the window that pops up. I get a Magento looking page (I am using the demo data) with the customer service / mini cart etc bits on the left and right columns, and nothing in the middle of the page. I don't want any of this on the page at all - I want to show my html, and only my html.

I have been using Alan Storm's documents as my source when setting up the following, but I am clearly missing something (or quite a lot!).

My JS is doing a window.open on "/index.php/myfrontname/moreDetails/moredetails", and here are what I think are the relevant files for this issue:

config.xml:

```
<config>
    ...
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>mymodule_moredetails.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
             </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/controllers/MoreDetailsController.php:

```
<?php
class MyPackage_MyModule_MoreDetailsController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function moredetailsAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();   // I'm still not clear as to what layout this loads.
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule_moredetails.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <mymodule_mycontroller_myaction>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_system_config_moreDetails" name="root"/>
        </reference>
    </mymodule_mycontroller_myaction>
</layout>
```

app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/MoreDetails.php:

```
<?php
class Mypackage_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_MoreDetails extends Mage_Core_Block_Template // also tried extending Mage_Core_Block_Text
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
            $this->setTemplate('mypackage/system/config/more_details.phtml');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/mypackage/system/config/more_details.phtml:

```
<HTML>
    ...
</HTML>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Your controller is a frontend controller, which means that it is loading the frontend XML files (as opposed to your own). First things first, have your controller descend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`, rather than `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`.

Next, please post the part of your config file where you set up the routes for the controller.

---

Okay, switch your `<use>standard</use>` block to `<use>admin</use>`. Here's the relevant block from adminhtml to give you a point of reference:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_Adminhtml</module>
                <frontName>admin</frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

When you do this, you should be using your adminhtml XML layout file and hopefully will have better results. If not, let me know and we'll keep going :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed my controller so that it extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action and rather than bring up an empty-ish front end shopping page, it brings up the Magento Admin Panel screen. This is the part of my config.xml you asked for: `<routers>
  <mymodule>
   <use>standard</use>
   <args>
    <module>MyPackage_MyModule</module>
    <frontName>myfrontname</frontName>
   </args>
  </mymodule>
 </routers>`  The above routers section is inside <config><frontend>. I kinda got things to behave as I want by just getting controller action to return my html.

Comment: In my last comment I said that I got things working by just doing `public function moredetailsAction()
 {
  $block = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
  $block->setText(big html string);
  echo $block->toHtml();
 }`, well that only works if extend `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`. If I extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` then I still get the Admin Panel screen.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed you had updated your original answer. I am really struggling to understand what you mean. Do I add the admin section above to my config.xml? And do I add it exactly as you have it? Sorry, I'm just really tearing my hair out trying to tie all these bits of config together. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not the identical block, but you need to structure your XML after that one. The top level tag is always `<config>`, but your next tag should be `<admin>`, as in the example. Replace your `<use>` section as well and see if that improves the situation.